# Heroku pricing is per app or per account?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

Hello for what i read in heroku pricing i understand the plan you hire is per account, what i mean is that you pay your e.g hobby plan + a basic 10m rows database, you can have up to 100 apps with that account and with the basic dyno + 10M rows.

Now im actually trying to buy that and the only way i found to buy is entering in the app itself, what makes me think that the plan im hiring is only for that app.

so if i hire a plan is for that particular app or for the entire account?

Comment: ask heroku not stackoverflow. this is off topic

Comment: already did, but maybe someone else knows and this may help someone else also, thats why i posted here

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Heroku pricing models.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heroku pricing is per-dyno, so essentially per-project (although a project can have more than 1 dyno). Database pricing is also per-project.

Pricing is never per-account.